# group pandas dataframe by continue float value (x-axis)?

Tags: pandas-groupby

I need to make new df by x-value

ex.

df_1 >>>x-value is 2000-2300

df_2 >>>x-value is 2300-2800

df_3 >>>x-value is 2800-3500

...

how can I get range x-value(continue float value) without plot graph?

here sample df

[sample pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYtnZ.png)

[this data look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv8Qa.png)

```
df.head()
X = [1089.818728,916.0439070000001,4275.421420000001,1650.879383,1769.973982]
Y = [788.5,1685.58,3276.11,2117.01,1870.11]
'X': {'count': 35269.0,
  'mean': 2770.332048115335,
  'std': 3398.8104089087337,
  'min': 606.576038,
  '25%': 1441.449553,
  '50%': 1877.575007,
  '75%': 2862.69605,
  'max': 67370.420428},
 'Y': {'count': 35269.0,
  'mean': 2168.9017117014914,
  'std': 1079.4422542889504,
  'min': 37.38,
  '25%': 1361.85,
  '50%': 2008.96,
  '75%': 2798.47,
  'max': 6738.99}}

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 35269 entries, 2 to 66521
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0     X           35269 non-null  float64
 1     Y           35269 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 826.6 KB
```

Comment: You should have posted sample data as text.

Comment: sorry, data so long (range 0-50,000) I dont know how to add csv here

Comment: You can add any text between lines containing only ```. A sample of a dataframe is well posted from the output of `df.head().to_dict()` and perhaps `df.info()`.

Comment: There is no _x-value_ in the shown data, only `volume` and `y`.

Comment: thanks, 'volume' mean 'x-value' I added new info. refer above

Answer (score 0):

> df_1 >>>x-value is 2000-2300
>
> df_2 >>>x-value is 2300-2800
>
> df_3 >>>x-value is 2800-3500

If you really want to extract individual data frames, you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df_1 = df.query('2000<=X<=2300')
df_2 = df.query('2300<=X<=2800')
df_3 = df.query('2800<=X<=3500')
```

But if you rather want [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you can do this with [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
by = pandas.cut(df['X'], [2000, 2300, 2800, 3500])
df.groupby(by)
```

For example this can be used to get counts of the entries like in your *sample pic*:

```
df.groupby(by).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can I specific range of  x-value by dynamic? because I must open each csv plot data and find range of  x-value

Comment: Yes, you can; I probably could even show how if you would explain what exactly you mean by _dynamic_.

Comment: Or are you only looking for `df.X.min()` and `df.X.max()`?

Comment: training model will less error if I cut data by x-axis  (refer to pic data will stick in some range in  x-axis ex. 2000-2300, 2300-2800) each data will have 4-5 groups but range in  x-axis not the same. I want to know how to get dynamic range in  x-axis.

Comment: You somehow have to make up your mind how _exactly_ you want to define the groups. One straightforward way would be to consider values to belong to different groups if a certain gap is between them. This can be done as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923942/2413201); don't forget to sort the X values.